# Format string to phone number with (123) 456-6789 pattern using dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
void main() {

  String phoneNumber = '123456789';

  String formattedPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst("(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)", "(\$1) \$2-\$3");

  print('Formatted number ${formattedPhoneNumber}');

}
```

**Output:**

Formatted number 123456789

I want output as Formatted number (123) 456-6789

Comment: Have you tried [phone_number](https://pub.dev/packages/phone_number#-readme-tab)?

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
print('1234567890'.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)'), (Match m) => "(${m[1]}) ${m[2]}-${m[3]}"));
```

Answer (score 11):

**Create a custom Masked class**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MaskedTextController extends TextEditingController {
  MaskedTextController({String text, this.mask, Map<String, RegExp> translator})
      : super(text: text) {
    this.translator = translator ?? MaskedTextController.getDefaultTranslator();

    this.addListener(() {
      var previous = this._lastUpdatedText;
      if (this.beforeChange(previous, this.text)) {
        this.updateText(this.text);
        this.afterChange(previous, this.text);
      } else {
        this.updateText(this._lastUpdatedText);
      }
    });

    this.updateText(this.text);
  }

  String mask;

  Map<String, RegExp> translator;

  Function afterChange = (String previous, String next) {};
  Function beforeChange = (String previous, String next) {
    return true;
  };

  String _lastUpdatedText = '';

  void updateText(String text) {
    if(text != null){
      this.text = this._applyMask(this.mask, text);
    }
    else {
      this.text = '';
    }

    this._lastUpdatedText = this.text;
  }

  void updateMask(String mask, {bool moveCursorToEnd = true}) {
    this.mask = mask;
    this.updateText(this.text);

    if (moveCursorToEnd) {
      this.moveCursorToEnd();
    }
  }

  void moveCursorToEnd() {
    var text = this._lastUpdatedText;
    this.selection = new TextSelection.fromPosition(
        new TextPosition(offset: (text ?? '').length));
  }

  @override
  void set text(String newText) {
    if (super.text != newText) {
      super.text = newText;
      this.moveCursorToEnd();
    }
  }

  static Map<String, RegExp> getDefaultTranslator() {
    return {
      'A': new RegExp(r'[A-Za-z]'),
      '0': new RegExp(r'[0-9]'),
      '@': new RegExp(r'[A-Za-z0-9]'),
      '*': new RegExp(r'.*')
    };
  }

  String _applyMask(String mask, String value) {
    String result = '';

    var maskCharIndex = 0;
    var valueCharIndex = 0;

    while (true) {
      // if mask is ended, break.
      if (maskCharIndex == mask.length) {
        break;
      }

      // if value is ended, break.
      if (valueCharIndex == value.length) {
        break;
      }

      var maskChar = mask[maskCharIndex];
      var valueChar = value[valueCharIndex];

      // value equals mask, just set
      if (maskChar == valueChar) {
        result += maskChar;
        valueCharIndex += 1;
        maskCharIndex += 1;
        continue;
      }

      // apply translator if match
      if (this.translator.containsKey(maskChar)) {
        if (this.translator[maskChar].hasMatch(valueChar)) {
          result += valueChar;
          maskCharIndex += 1;
        }

        valueCharIndex += 1;
        continue;
      }

      // not masked value, fixed char on mask
      result += maskChar;
      maskCharIndex += 1;
      continue;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

**Now call it in your main dart file**

```
var maskedController = MaskedTextController(mask: '(000) 000-0000');

TextField(
  controller: maskedController,
  style: Styles.textNormalStyle,
  maxLines: 1,
),
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution work for your this specific Question and scenario.

you can achieve using following code.

```
String formattedPhoneNumber = "(" + phoneNumber.substring(0,3) + ") " + 
phoneNumber.substring(3,6) + "-" +phoneNumber.substring(6,phoneNumber.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ricardo pointed to a great library but his answer is half right. Besides the `intl_phone_number_input` you need to get `libphonenumber_plugin` installed as well.

```
intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
libphonenumber_plugin:
```

The method `getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber` "discovers" what country the number is from eg +55... it would interpret as it's from Brasil and proceed to format the phone number accordingly. You can also explicitly tell from where the phone number is from passing the country's acronym into the method eg. `await PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber(phone, "US");` It'll disregard a country code if it doesn't fit the number you're entering.

```
String phone = "+19795555555";
PhoneNumber number =
  await PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber(phone);
String formattedNumber = await PhoneNumberUtil.formatAsYouType(
number.phoneNumber!,
number.isoCode!,
);
print(formattedNumber); // -> prints: '+1 979-555-5555'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use extensions:

```dart
extension StringExtension on String {
  String phoneFormat() => replaceAllMapped(
        RegExp(r'(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)'),
        (final Match m) => '${m[1]} (${m[2]}) ${m[3]}-${m[4]}',
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use: https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input/example

```
String phoneNumber =  '+234 500 500 5005';
PhoneNumber number = await PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
String parsableNumber = number.parseNumber();
`controller reference`.text = parsableNumber
```